# SSO for oracle forms on weblogic using security realms

Tags: oracle, forms, weblogic, single-sign-on

We installed Weblogic and used necessary steps to create and configure a provider in security realm. Using this provider we are able to retrieve specific users belonging to a group in our Microsoft Active Directory.

We would like to use this SSO technique with a Forms 12c application deployed on Weblogic.

Our difficulty is in accessing the username from within Forms when we use this technique. Is there a way to get the username?

One Oracle document is suggesting using OID & OAM to implement SSO for Forms.

Thanks